# .includes() with .filter() in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I'm trying to make a filtering method inside vue and one of the rules it has is to filter objects that their company id is in a the filtering list.

So basically the user can select multiple companies and vue will create a list for example `[1,5,2,6]` then this list gets parsed to the `processFilter()` method and it is supposed to now filter the products array to only have the products that their `company id` is in the list created by vue.

Product array example:

```
[
                {
                'id': 1,
                'name': 'Prod1',
                'min_price': '1',
                'max_price': '2',
                'currency': 'EUR',
                'image': '<Some_big_url>',
                'company': '1',
                'sub_category': '2',
                'created': '<some_big_date>',
                'views': '10000'
                }
            ]
```

My processFilter method:

```
processFilter() {
      const subCategory = this.filtersSub;
      const company = this.filtersComp;
      const sortBy = this.filtersSort;
      this.filtered = this.products.filter(
        this.data.includes(subCategory) && this.data.includes(company)
      );
    },
```

After testing this function method it returns the following in the console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
    at a.processFilter (category.vue:227)
    at submit (category.vue?c00e:1)
    at ne (vue.runtime.esm.js:1854)
    at HTMLFormElement.n (vue.runtime.esm.js:2179)
    at HTMLFormElement.Ji.o._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js:6917)
```

Is there a way to make this work or should I do it in a different way?

Before anyone asks yes I `console.log() company and this.filtersComp` and yes they are not `undefined` and have values in them as you can see in the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't how the logic inside your filter should work, but filter accepts a callback function, and you are passing just a bool here:

```
  this.filtered = this.products.filter(
    this.data.includes(subCategory) && this.data.includes(company)
  );
```

you can change it like:

```
  this.filtered = this.products.filter( product => {
    //if you console log here, product will be printed as many times as the
    //lenght of this.products applying the boolean
    console.log(product)

    //return this.data.includes(subCategory) && this.data.includes(company)
    //this will alway return the same value (true or false)
    //probably you want to use the product in your logic
    return product.sub_category.includes(subCategory) && product.company.includes(company)
   });
```

But this does not make much sense because the result of `this.data.includes(subCategory) && this.data.includes(company)` will always be the same at each iteration, resulting in all the elements being filtered, or not.
Most probably you need to use the `product` to actually filter you array.